# Sqljocky, transactioned query with multiple sets of parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, dart

I'm using sqljocky to insert data into a MySQL database. I need to truncate a table first, then insert multiple rows in it. I would do this in a single transaction, but it seems that sqljocky doesn't support this at all now (or maybe I'm quite new in dart and sqljocky).

The solution I found is the following, but I was wondering if there's a better one.

```
// Start transaction
pool.query('START TRANSACTION').then((r) {

    // Truncate table
    pool.query('TRUNCATE myTable').then((r) {

        // Prepare statement to insert new data
        pool.prepare('REPLACE INTO myTable (Id, Name, Description) VALUES (?,?,?)').then((query) {

            // Execute query inserting multiple rows
            query.executeMulti(myArrayValues).then((results) {

                 // Other stuff here
                 pool.query('COMMIT').then((r) {
                     ...
```

To be honest, I'm still wondering if this code really executes a transactioned query!

Comment: Note that `TRUNCATE TABLE` is a DDL statement, rather than DML: it causes an *implicit commit*.  One cannot therefore use it within a transaction in this way: you must instead use `DELETE`.

Comment: Thanks, there's always something new to know! :) I'll use DELETE.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the same code rewritten with transaction support:

```
// Start transaction
pool.startTransaction().then((trans) {

    // Delete all from table
    trans.query('DELETE FROM myTable WHERE 1=1').then((r) {

        // Prepare statement
        trans.prepare('REPLACE INTO myTable (Id, Name, Description) VALUES (?,?,?)').then((query) {

          // Execute query inserting multiple rows
          query.executeMulti(myArrayValues).then((results) {
              // Stuff here

              // Commit
              trans.commit().then((r) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ConectionPool.startTransaction()`.

```
*                                                              You
* must use this method rather than `query('start transaction')` otherwise
* subsequent queries may get executed on other connections which are not
* in the transaction.
```

Haven't tried it myself yet.

Comment: I had already found this function, but what I hadn't seen is the chance to prepare a statement with `Transaction` object! Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with 'prepare a statement with `Transaction` object'. Am I missing something?

Comment: I hadn't seen the `Transaction` object [extends](https://github.com/jamesots/sqljocky/blob/master/lib/src/transaction.dart#L9) `QueriableConnection`, which has a [function](https://github.com/jamesots/sqljocky/blob/master/lib/src/connection_pool.dart#L352) to [prepare a statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: I see, didn't know that either. I also just started using SqlJocky. Thanks for the info. I just saw, you already added the solution to your question. I think you should create an answer instead. You can accept your own answer.

Comment: Fixed, now the answer is properly posted! ;)